# Running `eb local run` as a background process from a bash script fails with various errors (described)

Tags: linux, bash, docker, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm trying to write a script that:

- Runs `docker-compose up -d` to orchestrate some services (database, etc.)
- Runs `eb local run` to start the web container.
- Connects the web container to the docker network created by docker-compose

The issue I'm having is with `eb local run` because it seems to be blocking, yet won't work as a background process.  Here's a sample of my script:

```
docker-compose up -d  #  Run backing services, postgres, redis, amqp, etc.

eb local run > ./logs/eb.log 2>&1 &  #  Run web container with eb

# Wait for container to be running
spin="-\|/"
i=0
until [ "$(docker ps -q --filter expose=8080)" ]; do
  i=$(( (i+1) %4 ))
  printf "\r${spin:$i:1}"
done

###  This section connects the elasticbeanstalk container to the network configured by docker compose
EB_DOCKER_CONTAINER_ID=$(docker ps -q --filter expose=8080)
DEFAULT_DOCKER_NETWORK_NAME="${${PWD##*/}//[\-\_]/}_default"
docker network connect ${DEFAULT_DOCKER_NETWORK_NAME} ${EB_DOCKER_CONTAINER_ID}
```

When I run this it prints `[2]  + 82322 suspended (tty output)  eb local run > ./logs/eb.log 2>&1` and is stuck in the loop waiting for the web container to start.

I've also tried some variations such as:

```
nohup eb local run &
```

Results in `[2]  + 82322 suspended (tty output)  ( eb local run; )`.  The nohup.out file shows that docker got up to building the image, but does not execute uwsgi.

Also if I run the `fg` command I get the message:
`unable to setup input stream: unable to set IO streams as raw terminal: interrupted system call`
***`ERROR: None`***

If instead I run `nohup eb local run` the container is run but the script doesn't progress past the `nohup eb local run` command.  The nohup.out file shows that uwsgi was started `*** Starting uWSGI 2.0.15 (64bit) on [Fri Oct  6 04:47:47 2017] ***`, however the web container is not connected to the docker network.

If I run `ps | grep docker` after the script has run, I do in-fact see the underlying docker run command. i.e.

`docker run -i -t --rm -p 8080:8080 --env KEY=VALUE -v /Users/me/Projects/my_api/.elasticbeanstalk/logs/local/171006_160403886032:/var/app/logs --name a81919b7750b87c5d6b0c85ad6088baef308d5de 06c07d928cea`

I invoke the script as `. ./bin/start.sh`, does anyone know how I could run `eb local run` from a script in this way, or any appropriate pointers/tips would be appreciated.

Comment: See if this helps `eb local run > ./logs/eb.log 2>&1 </dev/null &`

Comment: Hey, I tried that an the eb.log file says `the input device is not a TTY\n ERROR: None` and the command line says `[2]  + 16862 exit 4     eb local run > ./logs/eb.log 2>&1 < /dev/null`, thanks for trying though.